# Is it possible to authenticate a user in Azure AD from a SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted Add-In client side

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, azure-ad, adal

We are developing a **SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted Add-In** that calls an API in Azure. The API an App Service that has Azure AD Authentication and **OAuth implicit grant type**. Our wish is to authenticate the current user and do it on the client side, not use app permissions and run from code behind.

The catch is that a provider hosted add-in must have some url query strings like SPHostUrl. We cannot set the whole url in the App Registration Redirect Url, since SPHostUrl differs from site to site. When a user has logged in successfully in Azure AD, she/he will be redirected to the main page of Provider Hosted Add-In and loose SharePoint Context.